# Is this space subspace of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ Polish?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let  $D := \{ x \in [0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}} \mid \forall n: x_n = 1 \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 1 \}$
be the set of sequences in $[0, 1]$ such that if $x_n = 1$ for some $n$ then $x_{n+m} = 1$ for all $m \geq 0$.

I know that $[0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is Polish. Is $D$ with the subspace topology also Polish?

I can represent $D$ as a countable union of pairwise disjoint closed sets
$D = (\{ 1 \} \times \{ 1 \} \times \dots) \cup ([0, 1) \times \{ 1 \} \times \{ 1 \} \times \dots) \cup ([0, 1) \times [0, 1) \times \{ 1 \} \times \{ 1 \} \dots) \cup \dots \cup ([0, 1) \times [0, 1) \times \dots)$
but there is no theorem stating that such subsets are necessarily Polish.

I can also represent $D$ as a countable intersection as follows: translate the condition $x_n = 1 \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 1$ into the set $A = ([0, 1) \times [0, 1]) \cup (\{ 1 \} \times \{ 1 \})$. Then
$D = (A \times [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \times \dots) \cap ([0, 1] \times A \times [0,1] \times [0,1] \times \dots) \cap ([0,1] \times [0,1] \times A \times [0,1] \times [0,1] \times \dots) \cap \dots$.

To show that $D$ is Polish it is enough to prove that $A$ is Polish. (Then the sets $A \times [0,1] \times \dots$ and so on are all Polish (as countable products of Polish spaces are Polish) and therefore their countable intersection $D$ is Polish.) $A$ with the Euclidean metric is not complete. Is it possible to construct a compatible complete metric on $A$?

Comment: Just a comment to point out that the representation of $D$ as a countable union you give in your third paragraph is not correct. All sequences in which $1$ does not appear are missing from that union.

Comment: @MikeF Indeed, thank you. Editing thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $D$ is defined by universal quantifier over a countable set, it is most natural to write it as a countable intersection $\bigcap_n D_n$. Since $G_\delta$ subsets of a Polish space are Polish, it will be enough that $D_n$ is $G_\delta$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

We have

$$
\begin{align*}
D &= \{ x \in [0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}} \mid \forall n: x_n = 1 \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 1 \}\\
  &= \bigcap_n \{ x \in [0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}} \mid x_n = 1 \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 1 \} \\
  &= \bigcap_n \{ x \in [0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}} \mid x_n = 1 \}^{\mathsf{c}} \cup \{ x \in [0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}} \mid x_{n+1} = 1 \}.
\end{align*}
$$

Now, the first set in the union is open and the second is closed. Their intersection $D_n$ is then $G_\delta$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you. The link is that in metrizable spaces (here $[0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}}$), every closed set is also $G_\delta$.

Comment: @shashlik You are welcome!